# Summing cube roots in fractions

Tags: arithmetic

I found this problem, and understand the solution, but do not understand why they made the first assumption.
The problem:

[image]

The first line of the solution says that:

> The cube root of $1$ plus the cube root of $2$ plus the cube root of $4$ is a factor of $2-1$.

Why are you meant to assume this to solve the problem?

Comment: Note:  $\sqrt[3]4=\sqrt[3]2^2$

Comment: Have you noticed that each term is $$\frac{1}{\cbrt{t^2}+\cbrt{t(t+1)}+\cbrt{(t+1)^2}}$$

Comment: @RhysHughes the command to get cubic root is \sqrt[3]{}

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sum of reciprocal of sum of 3 cube roots](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2664341/sum-of-reciprocal-of-sum-of-3-cube-roots)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably they are telling you a way to rationalize the denominator so you can do the sum.

$1=2-1=(\sqrt[3]{2}-\sqrt[3]{1})(\sqrt[3]{4}+\sqrt[3]{2}+\sqrt[3]{1})$

Similarly

$1=3-2=(\sqrt[3]{3}-\sqrt[3]{2})(\sqrt[3]{9}+\sqrt[3]{6}+\sqrt[3]{4})$

and

$1=4-3=(\sqrt[3]{4}-\sqrt[3]{3})(\sqrt[3]{16}+\sqrt[3]{12}+\sqrt[3]{9})$

so you can multiply the first fraction by $\frac{\sqrt[3]{2}-\sqrt[3]{1}}{\sqrt[3]{2}-\sqrt[3]{1}}$, the second one by $\frac{\sqrt[3]{3}-\sqrt[3]{2}}{\sqrt[3]{3}-\sqrt[3]{2}}$ and the third one by $\frac{\sqrt[3]{4}-\sqrt[3]{3}}{\sqrt[3]{4}-\sqrt[3]{3}}$ and you get 
$$\frac{\sqrt[3]{2}-\sqrt[3]{1}}{2-1}+\frac{\sqrt[3]{3}-\sqrt[3]{2}}{3-2}+\frac{\sqrt[3]{4}-\sqrt[3]{3}}{4-3}=\sqrt[3]{2}-1+\sqrt[3]{3}-\sqrt[3]{2}+\sqrt[3]{4}-\sqrt[3]{3}=\sqrt[3]{4}-1$$

Comment: You're wrong: $$9-4 = (\sqrt[3]{9}-\sqrt[3]{4})(\sqrt[3]{9^2}+\sqrt[3]{9\cdot 4}+\sqrt[3]{4^2})$$ and similarily for $16-9$. What you need to decompose in this way is $3-2$ and $4-3$.

Comment: @AdamLatosiński thank you. It was a silly mistake, I edited my answer

Comment: This is NOT the sum!

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner my answer is the same as yours...

Comment: Yes your answer was updated!

Answer (score 6):

They are pointing to the fact (it's not an assumption) that $$ (x^2+xy+y^2)(x-y) = x^3-y^3$$
that is
$$ \frac{1}{x^2+xy+y^2} = \frac{x-y}{x^3-y^3}$$
If you use that for $x=1$, $y=\sqrt[3]{2}$, you get
$$ \frac{1}{1+\sqrt[3]{2}+\sqrt[3]{4}} = \frac{\sqrt[3]{2}-1}{2-1} = \sqrt[3]{2}-1$$
To get the other two fractions use  $x=\sqrt[3]{2}$, $y=\sqrt[3]{3}$ and $x=\sqrt[3]{3}$, $y=\sqrt[3]{4}$.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint to explain the quote:**

use $x^3-1=(x-1)(1+x+x^2)$ with $x=\sqrt[3]2.$